# Como salvar imagens em uma pasta do servidor via sockets usando python e opencv?

Tags: python, socket, opencv

Olá sou novo em programação e gostaria de saber como salvar imagens, (capturadas pelo opencv) em uma pasta criada pelo código dentro do servidor, sei que da pra fazer isso com o sockets mas n tenho ideia de como. o codigo abaixo captura o rosto cria uma pasta e salva 100 imagens detro dela, preciso q essa pasta fique dentro de um servidor.

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
haar_file = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
datasets = 'datasets'  #All the faces data will be present this folder
sub_data = raw_input ('digite o seu nome')     #These are sub data sets of folder, for my faces I've used my name

path = os.path.join(datasets, sub_data)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
(width, height) = (130, 100)    # defining the size of images 


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #'0' is use for my webcam, if you've any other camera attached use '1' like this

# The program loops until it has 100 images of the face.
count = 1
while count < 101: 
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 4)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))
        cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.png' % (path,count), face_resize)
    count += 1

    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Carlos, esse programa fica na máquina do cliente? E onde fica esse tal do servidor? Quem trata o servidor?

Comment: esse programa eu querer portar ele pra android .. vai ficar num celular pra testes... ele captura as imagens e salva numa outra maquina...

Answer (score 2):

Você sabe que "sockets" são um nível baixo de programação de redes, nao é? È um ponto onde você tem que se preocupar com cada byte lido, mandar mensagens - etc... são detalhes tão complexos, que no mundo real, existem protocolos construídos sobre os sockets para abstrair detalhes.

Então, eu poderia dar um exemplo de como salvar um arquivo ouvindo no "socket cru" aqui - mas iria ser algo complicado - teriamos que inventar um protocolo 'ad hoc' - nem que fosse para saber quando o nome do arquivo a ser salvo tivesse chegado - e mais pelo menos um campo para saber o tamanho do arquivo.

Bom, o HTTP é o protocolo usado pela Web, que coloca um bom número de abstrações em ciam das mensagens - ele especifica cabeçalhos, e métodos do tipo "Post" - assim, usando o framework Flask, por exemplo, seria possível fazer uma aplicação minimalista só pra salvar arquivos com talvez 5 ou 6 linhas no total.  Mas essa aplciação ainda exigiria que você tivesse que recuperar os dados e conteúdo do arquivo do corpo da mensagem HTTP, que é como o que é postado de um formulário de uma página web - tem mais alguma burocracia.

O Python no entanto, tem desde versões bem antigas, um servidor de chamada de métodos remotos que responde or HTTP, e codifica os parâmetros dos métodos como XML de forma transparente. Isso está na bibliotecapadrão do Python sob "xmlrpc".  A implementação do Python é de uma época mais "inocente" - não considera *nada* de segurança - e, no Python 2, nada de conversão de dados também. Ao mudar para Python3, o uso do xmlrpc do Python ficou um pouco mais burocrático - algumas considerações de consistência do servidor e conversão de dados de texto etnram em jogo - mas ainda vai ser ordens de grandeza mais simples do que fazer uma implementação equivalente em Sockets. (Só umas 5 vezes mais simples do que implementar em sockets sem nenhuma consideração de segurança, etc...).

Note que uma um servidor XMLRPC vai responder a qualquer request sem nenhum tipo de autenticação - nem mesmo um token estático - então, se você não estiver numa rede fechada entre o seu cliente e servidor, o melhor mesmo é usar o Flask ou Pyramid para colocar alguma autenticação - e configurar um servidor HTTP na frente, como NGINX para prover criptografia por https para seus dados.  (Mas se as duas máquinas estiverem na internet, lea sobre como criar "túneis ssh" - vai ser bem mais simples e seguro do que colocar um web-server com autenticação só pra isso. E claro, não se esqueça de configurar a firewall do servidor para permitir conexão à porta do xmlrpc apenas pelo túnel.)

Tendo isso em mente, exemplo de servidor XMLRPC Python para salvar um arquivo na pasta "data/" ([adaptado da documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html)):

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
from xmlrpc.client import Binary

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
with SimpleXMLRPCServer(("0.0.0.0", 8010), allow_none=True,
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler) as server:
    #server.register_introspection_functions()

    def save_image(name, content):
        # Dados do tipo "bytes" chegam aqui wrapped na classe "Binary"
        if isinstance(content, Binary):
            content = content.data
        with open("data/" + name.replace("..", ""), "wb") as file_:
            file_.write(content)

    server.register_function(save_image, "save_image")

    server.serve_forever()
```

E para usar o "save_image" no seu cliente, como se fosse uma chamada a um método local, bastam essas três linhas:

```
import xmlrpc.client
s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8010')
s.save_image(<nome_do_arquivo como string>, <conteudo do arquivo como bytes>)
```

Note que apesar de bastante inseguro, eu ainda coloquei um "replace" no nome para evitar um tipo de ataque muito simples em que no nome da imagem se coloca caminhos do tipo "../../etc/shadow" o que sobre-escreveria o arquivo de configuração de senha do sistema (se o xmlrpc estiver rodando como root, claro).

Comment: cara muito obrigado por responder... eu vou tentar ver oque consigo ...